# Connect java app to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect to sqlserver at my java application

I have search alot but no one of these method work

i use this

```
import java.sql.*;

public class testConnection
{
      public testConnection() throws Exception {  
            // Get connection  
            // DriverManager.registerDriver(net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver);  
          Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"); 

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/testnew", "sa", "123");  
            if (connection != null) {  
                System.out.println();  
                System.out.println("Successfully connected");  
                System.out.println();  
                // Meta data  
                DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();  
                System.out.println("\nDriver Information");  
                System.out.println("Driver Name: " + meta.getDriverName());  
                System.out.println("Driver Version: " + meta.getDriverVersion());  
                System.out.println("\nDatabase Information ");  
                System.out.println("Database Name: "  
                        + meta.getDatabaseProductName());  
                System.out.println("Database Version: "  
                        + meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());  
            }  
        } // Test  

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {  
            testConnection test = new testConnection();  
        }  
}
```

I'am sure that the user is work  but i can't connect to database

this is error message

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've not included the driver jar within the build/run classpaths of your application

Answer (score 0):

Download (for version 1.3.1, e.g. the current version) `jtds-1.3.1-dist.zip` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/), unzip it. Add the file `jtds-1.3.1.jar` to your build path.

You might also want to try with [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), which is also free and open-source.

Answer (score 0):

The class `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` does not exist in standard java library like `java.sql.Connection` and other classes.

If not already done, a separate jar file that is JDBC driver for MS-SQL Server called JTDS driver should be downloaded and added into the project Build Path.
By doing this the jar that contains the Driver and relevant classes are made available to the Java Runtime.

It does not complain before running the program as a compiler error, because the `Class.forName()` method takes the Driver class name as a string (or text). For compiler any text is valid, but when run it attempts to load the class with the given name into memory at runtime and it fails, either if it is not a valid class name or a valid class name but is not locatable (not in classpath).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        SQLServerDataSource sql = new SQLServerDataSource();
        sql.setServerName("Your SQL server name");
        sql.setUser("sa");
        sql.setPassword("your password");
        sql.setPortNumber(1433); // Make sure this port is open
        sql.setDatabaseName("Your database name");
```

Remember to add "sqljdbc_4.0.jar" to you project's library.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are missing the `jtds-[version].jar` in your classpath.Get the driver jar form [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/) and include it in the classpath.